# scikit-bio installation test failure, FAIL: _plot_box_data() should return a dictionary for Line2D's

Tags: python, anaconda, skbio

Installed scikit-bio on Mac, with dependencies for scikit-bio installed. Received error below. Traceback included. Followed instruction on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-bio for skbio test and used "conda install scikit-bio" which installed without error or issue.

Can someone help me understand where I am having issues? Thank you

---

```
TT0463-5:~ ron$ nosetests --with-doctest skbio
............................................................................./Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/alignment/_pairwise.py:594: UserWarning: make_identity_substitution_matrix is deprecated and will soon be replaced, though at the time of this writing the new name has not been finalized. Updates will be posted to issue #161: https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues/161
  warn("make_identity_substitution_matrix is deprecated and will soon be "
.............................................................................................../Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:59: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
EEE..........................F...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
======================================================================
ERROR: Test correctly handles coloring of box plots.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/draw/tests/test_distributions.py", line 492, in test_boxplots_box_colors
    fig = boxplots([[], [], []], box_colors=['blue', 'red', 'yellow'])
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/draw/_distributions.py", line 125, in boxplots
    whis=whisker_length, widths=box_width)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2636, in boxplot
    meanprops=meanprops, manage_xticks=manage_xticks)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3045, in boxplot
    labels=labels)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1965, in boxplot_stats
    q1, med, q3 = np.percentile(x, [25, 50, 75])
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3042, in percentile
    interpolation=interpolation)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2791, in _ureduce
    r = func(a, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3131, in _percentile
    x1 = take(ap, indices_below, axis=axis) * weights_below
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 121, in take
    return take(indices, axis, out, mode)
IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.

======================================================================
ERROR: Test functions correctly with empty distributions.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/draw/tests/test_distributions.py", line 470, in test_boxplots_empty_distributions
    "y-axis label")
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/draw/_distributions.py", line 125, in boxplots
    whis=whisker_length, widths=box_width)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2636, in boxplot
    meanprops=meanprops, manage_xticks=manage_xticks)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3045, in boxplot
    labels=labels)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1965, in boxplot_stats
    q1, med, q3 = np.percentile(x, [25, 50, 75])
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3042, in percentile
    interpolation=interpolation)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2791, in _ureduce
    r = func(a, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3131, in _percentile
    x1 = take(ap, indices_below, axis=axis) * weights_below
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 121, in take
    return take(indices, axis, out, mode)
IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.

======================================================================
ERROR: Test correctly throws error on invalid input.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/draw/tests/test_distributions.py", line 514, in test_boxplots_invalid_input
    boxplots([[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5, 6]], box_colors=['blue', 'red'])
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/draw/_distributions.py", line 125, in boxplots
    whis=whisker_length, widths=box_width)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2636, in boxplot
    meanprops=meanprops, manage_xticks=manage_xticks)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3045, in boxplot
    labels=labels)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1965, in boxplot_stats
    q1, med, q3 = np.percentile(x, [25, 50, 75])
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3042, in percentile
    interpolation=interpolation)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2791, in _ureduce
    r = func(a, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 3131, in _percentile
    x1 = take(ap, indices_below, axis=axis) * weights_below
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 121, in take
    return take(indices, axis, out, mode)
IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.

======================================================================
FAIL: _plot_box_data() should return a dictionary for Line2D's.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ron/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbio/draw/tests/test_distributions.py", line 245, in test_plot_box_data
    self.assertEqual(len(result['fliers']), 2)
AssertionError: 1 != 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 857 tests in 23.956s

FAILED (errors=3, failures=1)
```

Comment: This is a known issue with Matplotlib 1.4.0, this was [reported](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues/649) and has been fixed in the latest development version, see [this link](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/pull/700).

Comment: On top of @ElDeveloper's comment, the issue here is that the conda package version doesn't enforce matplotlib < 1.4.0, but it was also [reported](https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/issues/199) and should be fixed very soon.